# how do i add quotes to each listed item, a comma, a return, 3 spaces and then REPEAT

Tags: notepad++

I have a long list of items that looks like this:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2700
```

I need it to look like this:

```
   "item 1",
   "item 2",
   "item 3",
   "item 2700"
```

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+$(\z)?`
- Replace with: `"$0"(?1:,)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
(\z)?       # optional group 1, end of file
```

**Replacement:**

```
            # 3 spaces
"$0"        # the whole match (i.e. one line), surrounded with quotes
(?1:,)      # conditional replacement, 
                if group 1 exists (i.e. end of file)
                    do nothing
                else
                    add a comma
```

**Result for given example:**

```
   "item 1",
   "item 2",
   "item 3",
   "item 2700"
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]